# The text in the textview inside the table view cell is not formatted

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I am trying to build a Table View in which each cell contains a UITextView with formatted text. I got everything together, and the the table view gets populated by text. The problem is that when I test it in the simulator, the text is not formatted. It gets formatted only after scrolling, when it gets refreshed.

Here I am pasting below the view controller, which calls for the tableview and for the text (from a SQLite database), and the class I use to insert the text in the UITextView and format it. I have tried to force the layout of the container, but it does not work.

The View Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    self.myTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 200
}    

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("verseCell") as! VerseTextView
    let row : Int = indexPath.row
    var getVerse = databaseDB()
    var verse = databaseVars()
    (verse.book, verse.chapter, verse.verseText) = getVerse.getVerseBy(row, database: databasePath as String)

    if verse.verseNumber == 1  {
        chapterToBePassed = String(verse.chapter)
    }
    else {
        chapterToBePassed = ""
    }
    cell.configure(verseChapter: chapterToBePassed, verseText: "\(verse.verseText)")
    return cell
}
}
```

the VerseTextView class

```
class VerseTextView: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var verse: UITextView!

func configure(#verseChapter: String?, verseText: String?) {

// Formats
        var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = 15
        let font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
        let textFont = [NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
        let fontChapter = UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 22.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22.0)
        let chapterFont = [NSFontAttributeName:fontChapter]
        let myText = NSMutableAttributedString()
        var versettoId : String = ""

        if verseChapter != ""{
            let myTextChapter = "\n"+verseChapter!+"  "
            let capitolo = NSAttributedString(string: myTextChapter, attributes:chapterFont)
            myText.appendAttributedString(capitolo)
        }

        let testoVerso = verseText!+" "
        let verso = NSAttributedString(string: testoVerso, attributes:textFont)
        myText.appendAttributedString(verso)
        verse.attributedText = myText
//        verse.layoutManager.ensureLayoutForTextContainer(verse.textContainer)
//        verse.layoutIfNeeded()


    }
}
```

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("verseCell") as? VerseTextView

    if cell == nil {
         VerseTextView(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "verseCell")
    }
```

and implement `VerseTextView(style: Style, reuseIdentifier: ReuseIdentifire)`

in ur custom cell class

Comment: I tried, and I have implemented this in the custom cell class:    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)}. I was forced to add also: required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")}. But it gives me an error on the view controller, as it does not allow the  cell == nil for VerseTextView. I guess I am doing something wrong with the initialisation.